# Not able to get certificate from HttpContext which was send from HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

Well, I tried many different solutions but none seems to be working.
I have created Self Signed Certificate from IIS Manager and also import this to cert store.(Current User\Personal\Certificates). I tried to send that cert using below code part:

```
        var cert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\\Test.pfx", "asdf");
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual };
        handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
    
        var client = new HttpClient(handler);

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
        {
            RequestUri = new Uri("https://localhost:44351/helloworld"),
            Method = HttpMethod.Get,
            
        };
        var response = client.SendAsync(request).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        }
```

But I when tried to receive it, it consists of null.

```
       var clientCertificate = httpContext.Connection.ClientCertificate;
```

I think there exist some underlying concepts which I am not able to find out.

Comment: The certificate should not be part of the code.   HTTPS uses TLS for authentication.  Before the HTTP request is sent TLS does an authentication.  The server sends a TLS certificate block with a list of certificate names that is can use.  The client looks up the certificate until it find a match certificate in the user stores.